# Troubleshooting Submitting Watch App to App Store - Code Signing

Tags: ios, xcode7, watchos-2

I'd appreciate if anyone can help me with any or all of my errors I'm getting from trying to upload my new Watch App to the App Store (I already have a current iOS app). First I've followed this tutorial pretty close :

[Submitting Apple Watch Apps](http://basememara.com/submitting-apple-watch-apps-to-the-app-store/)

and it seems I'm getting hung up on a lot of code signing and plist problems.

[image]
[image]

So for the first one I don't understand how I would have 2 extensions like this screenshot:

[image]

The #2 error I've fixed, so I don't know why its still showing. #3 I don't know why it wouldn't be in the parent bundle's plugin directory nor do i know where to find that. #4 there isn't a key MinimumOSVersion in my extension plist. Nor is there for #5 but I wouldn't know what the value should be. #6 boggles my mind. #7 there isn't a DTPlatformName key in my extension plist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two things I can help, I think: You have two WatchKit extensions, you can only have one (error 1). I think watchOS 2 is only supported for iOS 9 and up (error 4). I think you'll get rid of some of the other errors by having only one extension

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right in that a few will go away once i fix the extensions. Do you know what part of the process I would have messed up to cause 2 extensions? Requesting certificates/provisioning profiles?

Comment: No idea unfortunately. I intially thought that you tried to do it with two extensions :) Since this isn't the case maybe some weird merge artifact if you are using source control or simply Xcode gone haywire. I would rule out certs/profiles though.