# Can't archive apple watch app - watchkitapp Extension.appex: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode7, watchkit

Can someone help me by showing me which option in Build Settings (and which target) points to this error?

```
error: /Users/user/.../Release-iphoneos/watchkitapp Extension.appex: No such file or directory
```

[image]

I've found a workaround to get my app to archive by going to that path in finder, copying and pasting the extension.appex file to the corresponding release-iphoneos folder during build time. This successfully builds the archive file but then multiple errors show up with that build.

[Troubleshooting Submitting Watch App to App Store - Code Signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756921/troubleshooting-submitting-watch-app-to-app-store-code-signing)

Which leads me to think is why I get this duplicate when submitting that build:

[image]

Thanks in advance if anyone has any suggestions.